# d2: immutability of partially known structures

Tags: immutability, d

In D, `immutable` is transitive, so assignments to any field of immutable structure is prohibited. As far as I understand, immutable structure variable is strongly guaranteed to be *never ever* changed, and all it's contents too.

But what if I have declared thing like this?

```
struct OpaqueData;
immutable(OpaqueData*) data;
```

How can D guarantee transitive immutability of structure not implemented in D and possibly having indirections?

What is right way to encapsulate such kind of pointer to opaque data in immutable class?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you don't know of any fields in `OpaqueData`, you can't assign to any contents of it in the first place.

You can, of course, break the type system entirely by casting away `immutable` (D does give you the power to do so) and assigning to the raw memory an `OpaqueData*` value points to, but then you're asking for whatever problems you'll end up with... If you don't do this and respect that your `OpaqueData` pointer is `immutable`, you cannot alter it in any way due to the transitive nature of type qualifiers.

This is, in fact, the entire point of them: They are mathematically sound.

Comment: Okay, you're right. I thought about D guaranties **out** of D scope - when immutable struct pointer is passed to C function. Indeed it's impossible, at least because `immutable` should be casted away before passing immutable struct pointer to C function, breaking type system. Thank you for helping me figure that out.

Comment: Yeah. Since the strongest that C has is `const`, and C can cast that away, you're pretty much taking your fate into your own hands if you pass `immutable` data to a C function (the same with `const` really, since it's just as illegal to mutate `const` data in D - it's just that other references to that data can still mutate it). If the C function actually treats it as `const`, then you're fine, but if it doesn't you're going to have problems.